# i want to fix my table view while i am scrolling

Tags: iphone, uitableview

while i am scrolling my table view gets moving upwards ..
i hav created table view programmatically without using IB so i should able to fix the position of table view while scrolling also...
how to do this..
any suggestions appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you dont want the table to scroll at all? If so then this should do it.

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you embedding a UITableView in a UIScrollView? It sounds like it. Don't. UITableView is already a subclass of UIScrollView and supports scrolling on its own.